# The program doesn't end when player 1 life reaches 0

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a little game using the Java Swing, in which there are four bottoms: attack player 1, attack player 2, regenerate player 1, regenerate player 2. When attack player 1 or attack player 2 push bottom are pressed, it removes -25 from the life of the player, vice versa, when regenerate bottoms are pressed it adds +15 to player's life. Now, everything works perfectly here, but when life reaches zero, the player is dead and the label text changes in: "Player 1 is dead" or "Player2 is dead", but this never happens:

[image: 1]

as you can see from the picture, player 1 life has been incremented and player 2 life even reached -50, this is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Swing16 implements ActionListener {
    static int life1 = 100;
    static int life2 = 100;
    JLabel AttRig;
    
    
    Swing16() {
        // Imposta le impostazioni del frame
                JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("game");
                // Layout basico
                jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                // Grandezza del frame (500 x 500).
                jfrm.setSize(500, 500);
                // Esci dal programma se l'utente esce dal frame.
                jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                
                
                JButton attacca1  = new JButton("Attack player one (-25)"); //Attack player two (-25)
                JButton rigenera1 = new JButton("Attack player two (-25)"); // Regenerate player one (+15)
                JButton attacca2  = new JButton("Regenerate player one (+15)"); // Attack player one (-25)
                JButton rigenera2 = new JButton("Regenerate player two (+15)");
    
        // Aggiungi action listeners per i push bottom.
        attacca1.addActionListener(this);
        attacca2.addActionListener(this); // rigenera1.addActionListener(this);
        rigenera1.addActionListener(this);
        rigenera2.addActionListener(this);
        // Aggiung pulsanti.
        jfrm.add(attacca1);
        jfrm.add(attacca2);
        jfrm.add(rigenera1);
        jfrm.add(rigenera2);
        // Nuovo label.
        AttRig = new JLabel("Player 1 life: 100 | Player 2 life: 100");
    
        // Aggiungi label al frame 
        jfrm.add(AttRig);
        // Visibilità del frame 
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    
    }

    // Cosa succede se i bottoni vengono cliccati.
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Attack player two (-25)")) {
                life2 = life2 - 25;
                AttRig.setText("Player 1 life: " + life1 + " | " + "Player 2 life: " + life2);
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Regenerate player one (+15)")){
                life1 = life1 + 15;
                AttRig.setText("Player 1 life: " + life1 + " | " + "Player 2 life: " + life2);
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Attack player one (-25)")) {
                life1 = life1 - 25;
                AttRig.setText("Player 1 life: " + life1 + " | " + "Player 2 life: " + life2);
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Regenerate player two (+15)")) {
                life2 = life2 + 15;
                AttRig.setText("Player 1 life: " + life1 + " | " + "Player 2 life: " + life2);
            }   
            else if(life1 < 0) {
                AttRig.setText("Player 1 dies...");
            }
            else if(life2 < 0) {
                AttRig.setText("Player 2 dies...");
            }
            
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Swing16();
        }
        
    });
    
  }
}
```

what may I do make restart the program through another push bottom? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try and remove the `else` from `else if(life1 < 0)` to make it a normal `if`, otherwise those 2 blocks will never be reachable i guess because one of the previous if blocks is always entered.

Comment: You might want to learn how to step through your code with a debugger to catch those things yourself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the life values after(!) you changed them.

In `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method, the following else if part should be 2 separate if statements as follows:

```
        if(life1 < 0) {
            AttRig.setText("Player 1 dies...");
        }
        if(life2 < 0) {
            AttRig.setText("Player 2 dies...");
        }
```

So it should look like this:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Attack player two (-25)")) {
            life2 = life2 - 25;
            AttRig.setText("Player 1 life: " + life1 + " | " + "Player 2 life: " + life2);
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Regenerate player one (+15)")){
            life1 = life1 + 15;
            AttRig.setText("Player 1 life: " + life1 + " | " + "Player 2 life: " + life2);
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Attack player one (-25)")) {
            life1 = life1 - 25;
            AttRig.setText("Player 1 life: " + life1 + " | " + "Player 2 life: " + life2);
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Regenerate player two (+15)")) {
            life2 = life2 + 15;
            AttRig.setText("Player 1 life: " + life1 + " | " + "Player 2 life: " + life2);
        }   

        if(life1 < 0) {
            AttRig.setText("Player 1 dies...");
        }
        if(life2 < 0) {
            AttRig.setText("Player 2 dies...");
        }
        
}
```